# Error Warning: Declaration of description_walker::start_el after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, functions, updates, warnings

I upgraded my PHP to 7.0 and after this I have this message in the header of my website:

```
Warning: Declaration of description_walker::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /homepages/2/d444683358/htdocs/wp-content/themes/zend/functions.php on line 59
```

Here is the line `59` in functions.php:

```
$output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
```

I'm not a coder so not sure what needs to be done to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It would be probably best to report it to theme's developers/support.

Answer (score 32):

The error message shows that the class `description_walker` extends the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class and overrides the `start_el()` method, but the signature differs from the method definition in the parent class.

As mentioned in comments, it would be best to contact the developer of your theme and ask for a corrected version of the theme.

If the developer cannot be reached or you really want to correct the theme yourself, you can do the following. But keep in mind that any changes to the theme files are overwritten on theme update.

Search the theme files for the function definition of `start_el()` inside the `description_walker` class. The line of code should look similar to this:

```
function start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
```

Changing this line to the following should make the warning disappear:

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
```

Comment: So, it is a PHP version cap issue?. This problem only started when moving a site from another host with diffrent PHP version... Strange I felt, no errors before... However this answer solved the Warning, as Im the owner of the theme walker... Thanks for a good answer as good it can be!

Comment: @JonasLundman This issue existed before PHP7 but in earlier versions, the warnings emitted had an error level of `E_STRICT`. Since PHP 7 they are normal warnings, hence they are shown with default error level settings.

Comment: Thank you mate, you saved me ;)

Comment: Awesome man, thank you!